# Is there the specialisation map of etale K theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, etale-cohomology

Take a smooth proper morphism of schemes $X\to S$. Fix a point $t\in S$ and a point $s\in \overline\{s\}$. For a prime $l$ which is invertible in $S$, is there the natural specialization map of etale K theory
$$
K^{{\acute{e}}t}(X_{\overline{s}})^{\wedge}_l \to K^{{\acute{e}}t}(X_{\overline{t}})^{\wedge}_l?
$$

Comment: Did you intend to write that one of $s$ or $t$ is in the closure of the singleton set of the other element?  That is not what you wrote above.

Comment: Where you wrote $s\in\overline\{s\}$, might you have intended $s\in\overline{\{s\}}$? $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots$ or $s\in\overline{\{t\}}$? $\qquad$